# Export to text file after executing Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, export

Here is my code

```
USE [test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE        [dbo].[DO_CUSTOMER_DAILY]
@tmpVar        BIGINT,
@V_SQL_TMP     VARCHAR (4000),
@V_DIRECTORY   VARCHAR (128),
@V_FILE_NAME   VARCHAR (128),
@V_COUNT       BIGINT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
set @tmpVar = 0


/* DO_LOG ('start DO_CUSTOMERS_DAILY')

  DO_LOG('END  DO_CUSTOMERS_DAILY'),

  DO_LOG('Start EXPORT DO_CUSTOMERS_DAILY')*/

SET @V_DIRECTORY = 'TBEX_DIR_DAILY'
SET @V_FILE_NAME = 'in_customer.txt'
SET @V_SQL_TMP =
'bcp
 "SELECT  INSTITUTE,
    lpad(CUSTNO,16) CUSTNO,
    rpad(NVL(FIRSTNAME, ''.''),32) FIRSTNAME,
    rpad(NVL(LASTNAME, ''.''),32) LASTNAME,
    rpad(NVL(STREET,'' ''),32) STREET,
    rpad(NVL(ZIP,'' ''),7) ZIP,
    rpad(NVL(TOWN,'' ''),28) TOWN,
    rpad(NVL(H_COUNTRY,'' ''),3) H_COUNTRY,
    rpad(NVL(S_COUNTRY,'' ''),3) S_COUNTRY,
    rpad(NVL(CUSY,'' ''),8) CUSY,
    rpad(NVL(FK_CSMNO,'' ''),12) FK_CSMNO,
    rpad(NVL(PROFESSION,'' ''),32) PROFESSION,
    rpad(NVL(BRANCH,'' ''),32) BRANCH,
    rpad(NVL(BIRTHDATE,'' ''),8) BIRTHDATE,
    rpad(NVL(CUSTCONTACT,'' ''),8) CUSTCONTACT,
    NVL(EXEMPTIONFLAG,'' ''),
    lpad(NVL(EXEMPTIONAMOUNT,'' ''),11) EXEMPTIONAMOUNT,
    NVL(ASYLSYN,'' '') ASYLSYN,
    lpad(NVL(SALARY,''0''),17) SALARY,
    rpad(NVL(SALARYDATE,'' ''),8) SALARYDATE,
    rpad(NVL(NAT_COUNTRY,'' ''),3) NAT_COUNTRY,
    lpad(NVL(TOT_WEALTH,'' ''),17) TOT_WEALTH,
    lpad(NVL(PROP_WEALTH,'' ''),3) PROP_WEALTH,
    rpad(NVL(BRANCH_OFFICE,'' ''),10) BRANCH_OFFICE,
    NVL(CUST_TYPE,'' '') CUST_TYPE,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_01,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_01,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_02,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_02,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_03,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_03,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_04,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_04,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_05,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_06,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_07,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_08,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_09,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_10,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_11,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_05,'' ''),12) CUST_FLAG_12,
    lpad(NVL(CUST_FLAG_24,'' ''),1) CUST_FLAG_24,
    rpad(NVL(EMPLNO,'' ''),16) EMPLNO,
    rpad(NVL(PASS_NO,'' ''),17) PASS_NO,
    rpad(NVL(BIRTH_COUNTRY,'' ''),3) BIRTH_COUNTRY,
    lpad(NVL(BIRTH_PLACE,'' ''),32) BIRTH_PLACE,
    NVL(BORROWERYN,'' '') BORROWERYN,
    NVL(DIRECT_DEBITYN,'' '') DIRECT_DEBITYN,
    NVL(GENDER,'' '') GENDER,
    rpad(NVL(RISK_CLASS,'' ''),10) RISK_CLASS
    FROM TB_CUSTOMERS_DAILY
    ORDER BY  lpad(CUSTNO,16)"
    queryout "C:\in_customer" -c -T





   -- DO_LOG(V_SQL_TMP),
    --DUMP_EXPORT_DATA ( V_SQL_TMP, V_DIRECTORY, V_FILE_NAME,V_COUNT),


    --DO_LOG(End EXPORT DO_CUSTOMERS_DAILY),



     /* BEGIN TRY
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL,
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE, */


END
```

I've Create this procedure in SQL Server 2012. My expected output is after executing, it creates a **text file**. However it does not work. If you dont mind, Pls check DO_LOG query for me also.
If you have any suggested, give me some. Thank you at advance
this page sometimes makes me annoyed

Comment: Assuming "does not work" means the sp does not output a text file; are you looking for the file on the server c drive or your local machine?

Comment: Your bcp query is not tsql - sql server 2012 does not have lpad, rpad, nvl functions. Oracle does - so what dbms are you attempting to use with your bcp command?

Comment: @destination-data it does not output a text file

Comment: @SMor i'm doing with sql server. I can convert "lpad-rpad" later. But how could i do if i want output a text file